# Using external executable within powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, command, external

I am new to programming and need some help.. I need to write a powershell script and as part of it it needs to run an external executable... However I am having issues with the script not asking for an argument and even if I pass one it just seems to wait without asking anything.. so here is the part in question

```
#Part of my script
$app = "D:\project1\files\vshadow.exe"
$arg1 = "-da"
$arg2 = "Y"

& $app $arg1 $arg2v
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

This is what I get in the console

> PS D:\project1\files> C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.ps1
>
> VSHADOW.EXE 3.0 - Volume Shadow Copy sample client.
>   Copyright (C) 2005 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> (Option: Delete all shadow copies)

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

so the .exe is to clear volume shadow copies with a -da flag (clear all).. however the step requires a Y to continue.. this when I run from cmd.exe

> D:\project1\files>vshadow.exe -da
>
> VSHADOW.EXE 3.0 - Volume Shadow Copy sample client.
>   Copyright (C) 2005 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> (Option: Delete all shadow copies)
>   This will delete all shadow copies in the system. Are you sure? [Y/N]

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

any help would be appreciated

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530725%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says `-da` requires confirmation but does not provide a way to override. You might be able to pipe in the  user input... Try this -

```
echo 'y' | cmd.exe /c vshadow.exe -da
```

Comment: @tom1123 try this `& cmd.exe /c vshadow.exe -da`

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of PowerShell being able to act like an Expect script.

That said, you may be able to get around the user input requirement of the -da option.  Use a vshadow query to get all copies, then pipe to a foreach loop to do a vshadow delete (-ds).